# Same messages are repeating continuously in automation-fatal.log in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have faced the automation-fatal logs issue, In this log file I have seen same messages are repeating continuously. No other logs are added in this Logs files.

example Logs:

Sep 17 08:08:07.030 [conn117] insert my_database.myCol ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:243505 285ms
Wed Sep 17 08:08:54.447 [conn101] command anotherDatabase.$cmd command: { findandmodify: "myCol", query: { ... }, new: 0, remove: 0, upsert: 0, fields: {...}, update: {...} } update: {...} ntoreturn:1 idhack:1 nupdated:1 fastmod:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:124172 reslen:248 124ms
Wed Sep 17 08:10:24.370 [conn95] command my_database.$cmd command: { count: "cms.myCol", query: { ... }, fields: null } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:197368 reslen:48 197ms

Can you provide the suggestion how to rectify this issue?